# dynamically constructing this php call

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to dynamically construct a call like this. The only part that changes is `Some`

```
SomeQuery::create->findPk($id);
```

so it could be

```
WhatQuery::create->findPk($id);
OtherQuery::create->findPk($id);
```

I tried this, but not sure why it isn't working

```
$dynamic = "Some";
$tablename = $dynamic."Query::create()";
$$tablename->findPk($id);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using PHP >= 5.3, you can use the following :

```
$className = 'SomeQuery';  // or another one
$className::create()->findPk($id);
```

As a reference, see this page of the manual : [Scope Resolution Operator](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php)

But that's not valid for PHP < 5.3.

With PHP 5.2, you'll have to fallback to a solution based on [**`call_user_func()`**][1] -- or another function of its familly.

I suppose something like this should do the trick :

```
$className = 'SomeQuery';  // or another one
$created = call_user_func(array($className, 'create'));
$created->findPk($id);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you  have >= PHP 5.3...

```
$class = 'Some' . 'Query';

$query = $class::create();

$query->findPk($id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$tablename = $dynamic."Query::create";
```

And if it doesn't work, use [call_user_func](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.call-user-func.php) with `array($dynamic."Query", "create")`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Factory pattern to be used:

```
class QueryCreator {

   public static function create($queryTypeName) {
         if(class_exists($queryTypeName)) {
              return $queryTypeName::create();// to use your model.
                                             // I'd use return new $queryTypeName();
         }else {
            throw Exception("class ".$queryTypeName." does not exist");
         }
   }
}
```

usage:

```
  try {
    $query = QueryCreator::create("myQuery");
    $query->findPK($id);

  }  catch (Exception $e) {
     // whatever// throw it forward or whatever you want to do with it;
  }
```

Make sure that your Query types objects implement the same interface. otherwise you can get errors.